# Dumping all data from old HD to new HD

Tags: command-line, dd, copy-and-paste

Please advise the easy way dumping all data from an old 4TB HD, ext 4, to a brand new 4TB HD, NTFS format, no OS on the old HD.

The new 4TB HD will be used for data storage ONLY in another dual boot PC, for sharing data between Ubuntu and Win 10.

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Also asked on https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468904

Comment: `NTFS` doesn't support the same metadata that `ext4` requires, so you're going to have trouble with links, ACLs, tricky file permissions,  etc.

Comment: Copy/paste is kind of easy, be it all or some data.